# Why does SSMS install refuse to run?

Tags: installation, ssms

I'm running SSMS 2014, 12.0. I wanted to update to the latest version. So I downloaded version 2021 18.10 and ran the install. I get the message about "am I allowed to update your hard drive?", I click yes, the message box goes away, and ... nothing happens. The install never starts. There's no error message, no nothing.

I tried just double-clicking the install exe and I tried "run as administrator". My SSMS 2014 still runs apparently fine. I tried re-booting and that made no difference.

I can't show you a screen shot and tell you what the error message is because there is no screen and no error message. It just ... doesn't run. Nothing shows up in Task Manager. Maybe something briefly appears and goes away and I'm not seeing it.

I'm running Windows 10 version 21H1.

I checked the Event Log. I get three errors:

#1

Application: SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
at Microsoft.Sql.DataTools.ManagedBootstrapperApp.ManagedBootstrapperApp+<>c__DisplayClassb.b__a(System.Object)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

#2

Faulting application name: SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe, version: 15.0.18390.0, time stamp: 0x52974fc4
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x062e20c7
Faulting process id: 0x3d14
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8229bbaa1bef2
Faulting application path: E:\download\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 5b87a388-b624-4c91-8a43-5f6a2d3d3673
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

#3

Fault bucket 1696726991828465605, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe
P2: 15.0.18390.0
P3: 52974fc4
P4: Microsoft.Sql.DataTools.ManagedBootstrapperApp
P5: 15.0.18390.0
P6: 61572117
P7: 1c2
P8: 28
P9: System.NullReferenceException
P10:

Attached files:
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2061.tmp.dmp
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2208.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2228.tmp.xml
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2226.tmp.csv
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2256.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_SSMS-Setup-ENU.e_5ebda51cbdcbf486abe677b94bc2ddee49c5073_2b50d92d_669a8403-bdaa-4e0b-9915-3b5cc3b1f2e5

Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 5b87a388-b624-4c91-8a43-5f6a2d3d3673
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: c7543e061dcc3604e78bfc359cc0b7c5

I've been advised to run sfc /scannow. Tried that, claimed it found problems and fixed them, restarted, and ... no difference.

I've been advised to run chkdsk. Finds no problems.

Found a web page that suggests faulty RAM or other hardware problems, but this seems unlikely as I don't get this error when doing anything else, and I'm on this computer all day every day.

Found a claim that someone solved this problem by deleting all certs from the  Untrusted Cert folder. There were none there, so that's not it.

I have no idea what to do next. Is there a log somewhere I can look at that might give a clue?

Comment: Look for a folder called "Setup Bootstrap" - there may be some log files in there telling you where it bailed. (UAC is a common reason for this specific symptom, IIRC.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks. But hmm, I found a "setup bootstrap" directory with a log file dated 2015 which I presume was created when I installed the 2014 version of SSMS. Nothing newer than that. I found a Microsoft page on the log files dated 11/30/2021 that gives the same file name -- program files\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log, so it's not like the directory name changed with more recent versions. So ... I'm still stumped.

Comment: You might need syinternals process explorer or procmon or something to determine why the program is exiting, if it's getting killed before it can even _start_ a log file, the problem seems bigger.

Comment: Also wouldn't hurt to look through the Event Viewer -> Application Log to see if the process is crashing, there might be some clues there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I get the message about "am I allowed to update your hard drive?", I click yes, the message box goes away, and nothing happens. The install never starts. There's no error message, no nothing. Brand new laptop, I had installed VS 2022, 2019 & 2015 on it. I couldn't get the latest version of SSMS to install (18.12.1) but I was able to install SSMS (17.9.1) with no issues. Not sure what the problem with the latest version is.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when Windows Management Instrumentation service is not running.

1. Open `services.msc`
2. Find Windows Management Instrumentation in the list
3. Set the service to run `Automatic`
4. Start the service
5. Attempt to install SSMS again

Comment: Thanks! I've actually retired since I posted that question, so not my problem any more ... but I'm still curious. I'll have to try this.